# What is wrong to my call to sqlite_open_v2?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have this C++ function:

```
Database::Database(string dbName)
{
    int results = sqlite3_open_v2(dbName.c_str(), &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);

    cout << "Error code: " << results << endl;

}
```

The error code returned is 21 (SQLITE_MISUSE). What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your flags do not make sense

```
SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE
```

Read-only will fail if the database does not already exist, but the other flag will try to create it if it does not already exist. you must use the 
`SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` instead